# How to use registerForActivityResult with androidx.fragment.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, androidx

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcherImportFileSelection = requireActivity().registerForActivityResult(...
```

If the above code is placed in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception: LifecycleOwner MyActivity@868498a is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
```

If it is placed in the constructor or as a declaration, requireActivity() throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2021-04-17 15:15:41.948 27930-27930/net.biyee.onvifer E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
            ... 42 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{fba6d22} (e0d1f006-996d-4051-9839-4575a92e33dd) not attached to an activity.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:928)
```

I have the following in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.2'
```

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

**Update:**

The problem has been solved.  Please see [my exchange with @CommmonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142157/how-to-use-registerforactivityresult-with-androidx-fragment-app-fragment/67142395?noredirect=1#comment118680839_67142157).

Comment: Have you tried calling `registerForActivityResult()` on the fragment? You are calling it on the activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I tried because that was the most logic step, but I got "Cannot resolve method 'registerForActivityResult' ".  This is why I have "implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.2'" in my question to let experts see if that is a problem.  I must be missing something very basic.

Comment: Hmmm... that method certainly exists -- you can see it [in the source code to the 1.3.2 version of the library](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/fragment/fragment/1.3.2-source/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java.html). Are you getting that error message in the form of an IDE error (e.g., from a tooltip), or are you getting it from the build output? I have been running into problems with Android Studio 4.1.2 where the IDE seems to get confused over artifact versions and so I get random errors, but the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help that points me in the right direction.  The problem has been solved, but one mystery has arisen. I realized this fragment was in a library project WITHIN the app project. The library's build.gradle did not have 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.2'. Once I added it, registerForActivityResult() could be resolved. The mystery is that Android Studio automatically used generated and used ".gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.fragment\fragment\1.2.4" before that. I could not find "1.2.4" anywhere in the project.

Comment: "I could not find "1.2.4" anywhere in the project" -- you might be getting that as a transitive dependency from something other library. Anyway, I am glad that you got it working!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a register call outside the `onCreate()` method and in addition you need to put the `registerForActivityResult()` variable as a property of the fragment class. (Works only for `Activity` instead of `Fragment`!)

Register call example for **KOTLIN**:

```
val getContent = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
// Handle the returned Uri
```

}

Register call example for **JAVA**:

```
// GetContent creates an ActivityResultLauncher<String> to allow you to pass
// in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
});
```

This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java) will help you to understand and practice. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help here.  I am trying to understand what you mean exactly by "variable as a property of the fragment class. (Works only for Activity instead of Fragment!)".

Comment: It was meant that you cannot put that `registerForActivityResult` directly in the `onCreate()` method, but rather in as an own method like shown above. And this works only for an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`. That was all what I wanted to say with that :) Good look! I hope your question is answered. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  My question is about androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.  Did you mean that I should use it?

Comment: No you shoul call it from an Activity. Also take a look at @CommonsWare article, he sent you. There is a way and another as I told with the activity, shown in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Receive an activity result in a separate class](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate),

> Fragment classes implement the ActivityResultCaller interface to let
> you use the registerForActivityResult() APIs

So you can use it exactly as in an Activity:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<input_type> mActivityResultLauncher = 
            registerForActivityResult(<your_contract>, <your_callback>);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // just don't register here
        ...
    }

    // call this when needed (e.g. user presses a button)
    private void launchActivityForResult() {
        mActivityResultLauncher.launch(<input>);
    }

}
```